# What characteristics should I be looking in to choose a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, switching, high-current, powermosfet, device-characteristics

I have an application which I need to switch a 1000 W 24 V 40 A inverter on, and I do need a way to switch it on with a MOSFET (I don't understand the way how to choose it properly) although in the datasheet here: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303301000_Minos-MDT70N03_C5121599.pdf
it states that it can handle 70 A 30V although I know that power dissipation plays a major role in choosing a MOSFET but I have no great idea about it.

The question: is this one suitable, if not then how to choose it?

Comment: you'll probably want a TO-3 case design for that much current. make sure you feed it about half Vgs (max) for minimum on-resistance. btw; 24v*30a is 720W, not 1000.

Comment: why should it be half Vgs I am afraid of getting the MOSFET quite hot because of this?

Comment: It will get hot if you don't give it enough gate voltage. Gate voltage won't heat it in a switching on/off application, only with a high-ferequency PWM signal would you worry about Vgs being too high, and even then, not really. In other words, don't just feed it Vgs(th) when drawing large currents. For the dissipated heat you calc (Ids x Rds x Ids) to get W. For the temp above ambient you multiply that power figure by RθJC.

Comment: can you please tell me why shouldn't I feed it with full Vgs when drawing large currents(just want to have an idea). no mate, it is 40A not 30A so 24V*40A is approx to 1000W

Comment: you can feed it the full 20v, but there's usually no benefit (lower rds) to anything above half the max. I also like to leave a little headroom as you shouldn't usually run components at any of the the absolute maximum ratings. Too much gate voltage will damage the fet, too little will make it run hot under load...

Comment: assume that drawn current Ids is 40A and the RDS is 9.1m ohm so a total of 14.56W of dissipated power, this is the datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2009010933_Littelfuse-IXYS-IXTQ130N10T_C440376.pdf

Comment: but I can't get the RθJC(or not sure hot to calculate it) and guess I am gonna need a beefy heatsink because the ambient temp(of the room) could reach 50 C

Comment: it's 2.5C, so x 14.5 would be 36.25C above ambient, if you had perfect cooling. There's a LOT of caveats about junction to ambient resistance we're out of room to discuss; for example that datasheet assumes a max current for <10 seconds (note2).  you also need to apply the derating factor to the ambient temp. there's also the lower max current rating when hot (junction 100C) of 35 amps. and so on. TLDR; get a TO-3 package FET when dealing with >15 continuous amps, or maybe a few TO-220s in parallel with proper gate driving circuits.

Comment: I guess yes there are a lot although I am not very good at mechanical designs, do you recommend a video or a PDF that explain all these information? and can you please tell me how did you get the 2.5C value?

Comment: Thermal Characteristic
Thermal Resistance,Junction-to-Case(Note 2) RθJC 2.5 ℃/W .  i dont' have a single video, but there's several good ones about picking out a switching mosfet or reading mosfet datasheets. A relay is a a lot simpler, I  tend to use those for big current switching.

Comment: I had read it RθJC it is written 0.25 ℃/W, so how is it 2.5? and yes I guess relays would match although I need something more speedy.

Comment: that first line in my last comment is pasted from the datasheet.

Comment: Hint: since this is a one up get the lowest RDSon MOSFET at 40V or more that you can find. Be sure it has an avalanche rating to support your inverters kickback if it does that. The lower the RDSon the less heat you will need to get rid of.  The part number gives you 70 amps at 30 volts. If the last number was at least 40 it would work.

Comment: @dandavis FYI, TO-3 is archaic; it's labor-intensive to install, and doesn't handle nearly as much power as modern TO-247 and larger packages, which are generally cheaper and better available.

Comment: Your best bet may still be to find an inverter with *remote on* or similar means to switch from mW standby to operational. There are power switches in the inverter, it would be a shame to put one in series without need - just make sure they stay off at appropriate times, or get a chance to turn on. *1000 W 24 V 40 A inverter* is an example of *advanced specmanship*: for "real" 1 kW out, expect 1040 W in rather than 960 W: 45A@23.1V, 41,3A@25.2V.